# Unable to set NOSHAREAS attribute on executable in USS. chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=EF076043

Tags: mainframe, zos, uss

While installing the ported tools from Rocket on my z/OS instance I am running into an issue while installing `sudo`.  The package is from `sudo-1.8.6p3_b009.170419`

In the install instructions indicate to set the following extended attribute with the command `extattr -s sudo`.

When executing the command the following is returned:

```
IBMUSER:/rsusr/devtools/bin #>extattr -s sudo
FOMF0303I sudo: chattr() error: rv=-1, errno=8B, rsn=EF076043
```

`bpxmtext` for Reason code EF076043 returns

`bpxmtext EF076043`

```
zFS Wed Jun 5 13:43:05 EDT 2019
Description: Operation required owner privileges and user did not have them.

Action: Ensure that you are the owner of the object.
```

However, I am the owner of the object in question.

```
IBMUSER:/rsusr/devtools/bin #>ls -la sudo
-r-xr-xr-x   1 IBMUSER  OMVS     1478656 Apr 12  2017 sudo
```

There is another missing piece to the puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must be owner of the file and have write permission to set this attribute

Comment: Thanks @bill-schoen `chmod u+w sudo` followed by the extattr worked like a champ